# Capistrano Resque with one worker for production

Tags: redis, resque, mailer

I am really confused on how to get Resque and resque_mailer working on my production server. What I need to do is get a single worker running/restart which is called 'mailer' via Capistrano when I do a `cap deploy`.

I've seen this [gist](https://gist.github.com/andruby/797301) but I just don't get it. Is there something else that breaks it down to explain what its doing. Or is there a simpler solution to get this working?

I've already got Redis working as I'm already using it for other tasks.

My production server is as follows: Ubuntu, Apache, Passenger, Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I used Sidekiq. The documentation is much better and just works!